# Override and overload

Tags: java

My question is: Why `a4.equals(a2)` causes `method1` to execute and not `method2`?
`a2` points to `AA` and it is the parameter.
And the same about `a2.equals(b1)`.
It seems that when it doesnt points to `BB`(to the class where all the `equals` methods are) it will cause only `method1` to execute and it doesnt matter which type of parameter a method gets.

```
public class AA
{
    public int getVal()
    {
       return 5;
    }
}

public class BB extends AA
{
    private String _st = "bb";

    public boolean equals(Object ob)  //method1
    {
      System.out.println("Method 1");
        if((ob != null) && (ob instanceof BB))
        {
            if(_st.equals(((BB)ob)._st) && (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public boolean equals(AA ob)  //method2
    {
    System.out.println("Method 2");
        if((ob != null) && (ob instanceof BB))
        {
            if(_st.equals(((BB)ob)._st) && (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(BB ob)  //method3
    {
        System.out.println("Method 3");
        if(ob != null)
            if(_st.equals(((BB)ob)._st) && (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AA a2 = new BB();
        AA a4 = new BB();   
        BB b1 = new BB();  

        System.out.println(a4.equals(a2));
        System.out.println(a2.equals(b1));
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Why a4.equals(a2) causes method1 to execute and not method2?"_ because `equals(AA aa)` in `BB` is not an override of method `equals(Object o)` in `AA` since the parameter type does not match.

Comment: _"It seems that when it doesnt points to BB(to the class where all the equal methods are) it will cause only method1 to execute and it doesnt matter which type of parameter a method gets."_ exactly. You can only call methods on a type that are declared within it. Same names and same Parameter cound are not enough, THe types of the parameter must also match in the same order.

Comment: BTW: checking non-nullity before `instanceof` is redundant: `null instanceof AnyClass` [returns false](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only `equals` method known to `AA` class is `Object`'s `equals`, which accepts an `Object` argument. Therefore only `public boolean equals(Object ob)` can be called when calling `a4.equals(a2)` or `a2.equals(b1)`, since the compile time type of both `a2` and `a4` is `AA`.

The method that gets called in run-time is your "method1", since it overrides `Object`'s `equals`. The `public boolean equals(AA ob)` and `public boolean equals(BB ob)` overloads can only be called for references whose compile time type is `BB`, since method overloading is resolved based on the compile-time type of the object of which the method is called. If you call `b1.equals()` you will see your other methods being chosen, since method overloading will be used.

Comment: if possible can you point me to a link where i can learn about the above concept in  more detail.

Comment: @Abhishek Just Google "JLS method overloading resolution" and "JLS method overriding"

Comment: But when a4.equals(a2) is called, a2 points to AA and public boolean equals(Object ob) accepts Object and not AA. So it makes automatically UpCasting during runtime?

Comment: @Arthur It doesn't need to do any casting. `AA` has only one `equals` method - `public boolean equals(Object ob)`. Since you can pass any `Object` to that method (including a `AA` object), `a4.equals(a2)` can execute `public boolean equals(Object ob)`, and that's what it does.

Comment: @Eran But when `a4.equals(a2)` is called, `a2` points to AA and `public boolean equals(Object ob)` accepts Object and not `AA`. So it makes automatically UpCasting during runtime?

Comment: @Arthur Since any class is a sub-class of `Object`, you can pass any instance of any class to the method `public boolean equals(Object ob)`. It doesn't matter what the type of `a2` is.